# Spring MVC/Security - Users still can access login page after successful login

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am very new to Spring.

I am working with version 4.3.9.RELEASE of Spring MVC, 4.2.3.RELEASE of Spring Security.

I am using the built in login of spring with a little customization, here is my configure

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService myUserService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {       
        auth
            .userDetailsService(myUserService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .rememberMe()
                .alwaysRemember(true)
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();

    }
}
```

Why users can access login page after they logged in successfully? I tried to learn from the questions that are the same like mine, but none of them works with me.

This solution doesn't work with me:

```
<sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
  <% response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()); %>
</sec:authorize>
```

I am using Apache Tiles, I have is_authenticated.jsp with that  part. and this is the tiles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
        "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>
  <definition name="base" template="/WEB-INF/layouts/page.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="pageHeader" value="/WEB-INF/layouts/page_header.jsp"></put-attribute>
    <put-attribute name="pageFooter" value="/WEB-INF/layouts/page_footer.jsp"></put-attribute>
  </definition>

  <definition name="login" extends="base">
    <put-attribute name="isAuthenticated" value="/WEB-INF/views/is_authenticated.jsp"></put-attribute>
    <put-attribute name="pageBody" value="/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp"></put-attribute>
  </definition>

  <definition name="home" extends="base">
    <put-attribute name="isAuthenticated" value=""></put-attribute>
    <put-attribute name="pageBody" value="/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp"></put-attribute>
  ...
</tiles-definitions>
```

and here is page.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <t:insertAttribute name="isAuthenticated"></t:insertAttribute>  
    ...
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Page Layout HTML -->
    <header id="pageHeader">
    <t:insertAttribute name="pageHeader"></t:insertAttribute>
    </header>

    <main id="pageBody">
    <t:insertAttribute name="pageBody"></t:insertAttribute>
    </main>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

The is_authenticated.jsp is included and rendered but it doesn' work, it does work only if I put the  block inside the page.jsp itself, which looks wrong as you see, but it doesn't work when included from another jsp file.

Another solution, handling this issue from login controller, but this is not available in my case, because I didn't use any controller to handle login process. 
Should I do? 
The custom login controller will be more secure than the default one in Spring?

**Update1**

I tried to use the default login feature of spring:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService myUserService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {       
        auth
            .userDetailsService(myUserService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin();

    }
}
```

But I found that after successful login, user can still access login page.
So I am guessing I need to have a method in LoginController to accomplish this.

Comment: Why do you need to prevent access to login page for authenticated users?

Comment: @StanislavL
Am, I though that the login page should not be accessed if the user is already authenticated, as I used to experience with online web application.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it by using `access()` method:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


    http
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login", "/signup", "/")
            .access("hasRole('ANONYMOUS')")
            .antMatchers("/test").access("permitAll()")
            .antMatchers("/user/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .antMatchers()
            .access("hasRole('USER')").anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler()).permitAll()
            .failureHandler(loginFailureHandler())
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
}

private AuthenticationSuccessHandler loginSuccessHandler() {
    return (request, response, authentication) ->{
        response.sendRedirect("/home");
    };
}

private AuthenticationFailureHandler loginFailureHandler() {
    return (request, response, exception) -> {
        response.sendRedirect("/");
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer.

Since I configured `configure` method as this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .rememberMe()
            .alwaysRemember(true)
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll();
}
```

I was supposed to have `addViewControllers` in my implementation of `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`.
So I tried to remove this method and instead create a LoginController which only have `login()` method for `GET` requests that handle the redirect if the user is authenticated.

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=GET)
    public String login(Principal principal) {
        return principal == null ?  "login" : "redirect:/"; 
    }
}
```